# How do I implement an event listener when the key expires in Spring-Data-Reactive-Redis?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis, event-listener, reactive

Spring data redis may be implemented as follows.

```kotlin
@Component
class ExpirationListener : MessageListener {
    
    override fun onMessage(message: Message, pattern: ByteArray) {
        println("########## onMessage pattern " + String(pattern) + " | " + message.toString())
    }
}

@Configuration
class RedisConfig(private val env: Environment) {

    @Bean
    fun redisConnectionFactory(): RedisConnectionFactory {
        val redisHost = env.getProperty("CONF_TRANSACTION_GATEWAY_REDIS_DB_HOST", "localhost")
        val redisPort = env.getProperty("CONF_TRANSACTION_GATEWAY_REDIS_DB_PORT", "6379")
        return LettuceConnectionFactory(redisHost, redisPort.toInt())
    }

    @Bean
    fun redisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory): RedisTemplate<String, String> {
        val stringSerializer = StringRedisSerializer()
        return RedisTemplate<String, String>()
            .apply {
                connectionFactory = redisConnectionFactory
                keySerializer = stringSerializer
                hashKeySerializer = stringSerializer
                valueSerializer = stringSerializer
                hashValueSerializer = stringSerializer
            }
    }

    @Bean
    fun redisMessageListenerContainer(
        redisConnectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory,
        expirationListener: ExpirationListener
    ): RedisMessageListenerContainer {
        val redisMessageListenerContainer = RedisMessageListenerContainer()
        redisMessageListenerContainer.connectionFactory = redisConnectionFactory
        redisMessageListenerContainer.addMessageListener(expirationListener, PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired"))
        return redisMessageListenerContainer
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to implement it with `Spring data reactive redis`.

In particular, since there is no `addMessageListener()` function in the `RedisMessageListenerContainer`, the predefined `ExpirationListener` could not be used.